# Can I use Sass properties as args for my function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

It appears that I'm attempting to use SASS properties as arguments for my function, **AND IT'S NOT GOING WELL**.

Is there a way in which I can do this, or is there a better alternative to what I'm trying to achieve?

Basically, I want to change the values of variables I send to my function based on my screen width media query.

Currently:

```
@function myFunc($arg1, $arg2) {
    @debug "arg1 = #{$arg1} / arg2 = #{$arg2}";

    @return #{$arg1} * #{$arg2};
}

.my-class {
    // Mobile first values
    --var1: 10px;
    --var2: 20px;

    @media (--from-tablet-size) {
        --var1: 20px;
        --var2: 40px;
    }

    width: myFunc(--var1, ---var2);
}
```

The debug output actually shows that the values passed to the function is just the strings `--var1` and `--var2` rather than their respective property values...

```
DEBUG: arg1 = --var1 / arg2 = --var2
```

Is there something that I can do to solve this? Either by passing the properties as I am attempting here, or a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code:

1. For reading CSS variables `var()` is needed, for example `var(--var1)`. More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties
2. CSS variables can't use with SASS calculations or functions.
3. Two numbers with units can't multiply in SASS for example. What expected from `10px * 20px`? It should be something like `10 * 20px`.

First suggestion: Using SASS variables

```
@function myFunc($arg1, $arg2) {
    @debug "arg1 = #{$arg1} / arg2 = #{$arg2}";

    @return $arg1 * $arg2;
}

.my-class {
    // Mobile first values
    $var1: 10;
    $var2: 20px;
    width: myFunc($var1, -$var2);

    @media (--from-tablet-size) {
        $var1: 20;
        $var2: 40px;
        width: myFunc($var1, -$var2);    
    }
}
```

Second suggestion: Using CSS variables

```
.my-class {
    // Mobile first values
    --var1: 10;
    --var2: 20px;

    @media (--from-tablet-size) {
        --var1: 20;
        --var2: 40px;
    }

    width: calc(var(--var1) * -1 * var(--var2));
}
```